# Google earth network link deletes file

Tags: kml, google-earth

I had a very large My Places file, which kept crashing Google Earth. So i was advised to use network links: save the large file as (say) `Places1.kml`, and only have a network link in My Places to this file.

This seemed to work for a while. But now I have two problems:

- Once I open the file once,and then exit GE, if I come back in again, the file (Places1) has been destroyed (on disk, it just show 1kb)
- Assuming I can fix the above, I don't know to update this file. If I want to add a new place mark or polygon to this file, I seem to be able to move it there while GE is open, but if I try to save that network file, it crashes GE. So the network remains `static/unupdatable`. This is a pain.

Please advise.

Comment: Where are you storing your external KML files (e.g. places1.kml)? 'My Documents' folder?

Answer (score 0):

One method to clean up your Google Earth saved places file is moving your places to external files and including them via [NetworkLinks](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) as you've already started.

There still may be too many places loaded at once. You should add `<visibility>0</visibility>` to your NetworkLinks to make them load only when you check it manually. Continue moving more portions of your saved places into external files and add NetworkLinks to them then remove the original places from your 'My Places'. The desired goal is to keep your saved places file relatively small and fast to load.

Here is a discussion with more details to [manage a large saved places file](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#Managing_Places).

Google Earth deleting your external files is very unusual. Google Earth would just read those files from the local file system or network. Were files inadvertently saved in the temporary folder?

To edit your external KML, you need to manually load the KML file (e.g. places1.kml), make the changes, then "Save As" back to the same file location (e.g. My Documents/kml/places.1kml). The NetworkLink is only a reference (or link) to this file so you won't be editing the NetworkLink. Remember not to save the changed file to your "Saved Places" when you exit Google Earth.